# Filtering taskDetails.order_details using regex and get what is in output image

Tags: javascript, regex

**Output expected**
[image: Output]

I want to filter ***order_details*** (item details) just as shown in the picture which I am able to do in addition to this I also want to fetch

> *Tipo de papa:*  -\nPapa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n     *Adicional :*  - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n     *Agrega Bebida:*  - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n
>   *Salsas:*  - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji
>   S/0.00\n

How can I fetch this also The regex I have used to get order items could there be some more improvement?

```js
var opts = {
  "items": [{
    "mail_parser_label": "order_details",
    "label": "order_details",
    "data_type": "Table",
    "app_side": "0",
    "required": 0,
    "value": 1,
    "data": {
      "head": [{
        "mail_parser_label": "Detalle",
        "label": "Detalle",
        "type": "text",
        "arth": " ",
        "id": 0,
        "show": 1,
        "app_side": 0,
        "required": 0
      }, {
        "mail_parser_label": "Cantidad",
        "label": "Cantidad",
        "type": "text",
        "arth": " ",
        "id": 1,
        "show": 1,
        "app_side": 0,
        "required": 0
      }, {
        "mail_parser_label": "Unidad",
        "label": "Unidad",
        "type": "text",
        "arth": " ",
        "id": 2,
        "show": 1,
        "app_side": 0,
        "required": 0
      }, {
        "mail_parser_label": "Total",
        "label": "Total",
        "type": "text",
        "arth": " ",
        "id": 2,
        "show": 1,
        "app_side": 0,
        "required": 0
      }],
      "other": [],
      "body": []
    },
    "template_id": "NUEVO_PEDIDO",
    "appCheck": true
  }],
  "taskDetails": {
    "order_details": "Detalle\n Unidad\n Cantidad\n Total\n     Triple Insomnio Especial   S/37.90 1  S/37.90    *Tipo de papa:*  -\nPapa Amarilla Tumbay S/0.00\n     *Adicional :*  - Quesp cheddar S/0.00\n     *Agrega Bebida:*  - Fanta 400 ml S/0.00\n     *Salsas:*  - Mayonesa S/0.00\n - Ketchup S/0.00\n - Golf S/0.00\n - Guacamole S/0.00\n - Ají S/0.00\n - Tártara S/0.00\n - Mayo-aji S/0.00\n      "
  }
}

var items = opts.items;
var taskDetails = opts.taskDetails;
for (var p = 0; p < items.length; p++) {
  var parameter = items[p];
  if (parameter.mail_parser_label == "order_details") {
    var str = taskDetails.order_details.toString().replace(/[ ]+/g, ' ');
    var itemPatternFull = str.match(/[A-Za-z0-9 ]*S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g);
    var itemPattern = itemPatternFull ? itemPatternFull.toString().match(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g) : [];
    var details = itemPatternFull ? itemPatternFull.toString().replace(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g, '').toString().split(',') : [];
    var itemPatternLength = str.match(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g).length;
    var itemPattern = str.match(/S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*\s+\d{1,}\s+S\/\d{1,}[.]*\d*/g);
    var itemPatternArray = itemPattern.toString().replace(',', ' ').split(' ');
    str = str.split(' ');



    var count = 0;
    if (itemPatternArray.length < str.length && details.length == itemPatternArray.length / 3) {
      for (columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < itemPatternArray.length; columnIndex++) {
        if (columnIndex % 3 == 0) {
          parameter.data.body.push({
            "val": details[count].trim(),
            "id": count + columnIndex,
            "head": "Dettalle"
          });
          count++;
        }
        parameter.data.body.push({
          "val": itemPatternArray[columnIndex].replace(/S\//, ''),
          "id": columnIndex + count,
          "head": str[(columnIndex % 3) + 1] ? str[(columnIndex % 3) + 1].toString().replace('\n', '') : str[(columnIndex % 3) + 1]
        });
      }
    }
  } else {
    parameter.data = taskDetails[parameter.mail_parser_label].toString().trim().replace(/[\s+\n]/g, ' ');
  }
}
console.log("ITEMS", parameter.data.body)
```

Comment: You're missing something, so the code doesn't run currently: `itemPatternArray.length, str);`

Comment: Please check now made an edit @CertainPerformance

Comment: please fix the title to explain filtering **what**. data? html?

Comment: fixed the title @vsync